# My background images won't show in githubpages

Tags: angular, background-image, github-pages

Can someone help me? My background images are not showing up on GitHub Pages.

Repository link in HTML:
https://github.com/balicoelho/Angular---Portfolio-pessoal/blob/main/src/app/pages/home/home.component.html

GitHub Pages:
https://balicoelho.github.io/Angular---Portfolio-pessoal/

It´s written in Angular

In the code I wrote:

```
[urlImg]="'https://balicoelho.github.io/Angular---Portfolio-pessoal/assets/img/obc-logo.jpeg'"
```

but it doesn´t appear on the page. But if I search for this address on the web, the image is there.

Comment: well, if you look, it actually has some other path: `<div _ngcontent-mrs-c6="" class="formacao__card-img" style="background-image: url('../../assets/img/obc-logo.jpeg');"></div>`, if you replace it with `url('assets/img/obc-logo.jpeg');` it works, so check which version you have deployed, try also here: [deploy-to-github-pages](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages)